# Is adding finally block really necessary in try...catch

Tags: javascript, async-await

So i have been searching, is using a `finally` really necessary, and i guess i haven't found the answer i was looking for my type of use case. Here is the code example:

```
async fetchFromBackend() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  try {
    const res = await fetchData();
    return res;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  this.isLoading = false;
}
```

from the code above, the reassignment of `this.isLoading` won't be executed until it has done with the `await` without needing  to put it inside a `finally` regardless it will throw an error or not. Can someone elaborate if this would be the best practice or if the reassignment outside of try...catch suffice?

Comment: "finally" runs regardless. So thats how you would use it to preserve scope.

Comment: In general, `catch` would not necessarily catch *all* exceptions (ignoring them by logging them might not be the best approach here either, the function then returns `undefined`) and might itself throw an exception. For these cases, a `finally` block makes more sense - only in your example it hardly makes a difference.